# SSIS Survivorship Nodes

Tags: ssis

Are there any matching and survivorship nodes in SSIS besides the one offered by Melissa Data? Any implementations in SQL on survivorship would be great as well.

An example on my use case is that given that I have some 2 records of referring to the same customer, I want to come up with a golden record that will combine the demogs available (Example: record 1 has an empty email address, then record 2 has a filled up email address, golden record should return 1 row and the email address captured.)

Answer (score 1):

The requirement you described is a scenario where DQS - Data Quality Services along SSIS would become a part of your data processing pipeline.

SSIS focuses itself on moving frozen data from point A to point B as fast as possible with no losses. Whilst it does offer capabilities to enrich or correct the data in transit (using canned or 3rd party tools) one should not become obsessed offloading this concern to ETL entirely.

The best place to mutate data is in the Data Lake/Staging zone with audits and logs in place and desirably so the changes are monitored and follow an approval process.